# How to create mailer service in Java

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm working on webApp which one's feature will be to send invitation links to users by emails. I read about **JavaMail** but when I was testing this solution I noticed that it was working very slow. I was sending emails by my private gmail account and each email before send was authenticated and making this all magic staff which takes a lot of time.

So my questin is - how to do it properly? How to send thic invitation links faster? Maybe I need to buy some external smpt service or something like this? I'm totally newbie in this things so please just show me the way.

Thanks

Comment: Gmail has a limitation to the number of emails which may be sent from the API (250 or 500, I think).  You may look into other email services which specialize in handling higher volumes.

Comment: try mailgun or sendmail